# Access Docker Container Port in a Ubuntu VM

Tags: docker, ubuntu, vmware, ubuntu-18.04

Given an Ubuntu VMWare Machine (IP: `192.168.10.35`) that runs a docker image inside (IP: `172.0.18.2`) and given this `docker-compose.yml` how would I access the Docker Image from my local machine?

```
version: '3'

services:
    sc2:
      build: .
      ports:
        - 127.0.0.1:4620:80
      restart: always
      networks:
        - default
      volumes:
        - ./sc2ai:/sc2ai
        - ./apache/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
networks:
    default:
```

I tried to access `192.168.10.35:4620` but the connection failed. What am I missing? Is there an option in the docker-compose missing or do I need to forward ports from inside the VM to the docker image?

PS: If I start the image in `docker-for-windows` on my local machine I can access it via `http://localhost:4620`.

Comment: You're only binding to `127.0.0.1:4620:80`. Change that line to `4620:80` and what you have should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because you've explicitly declared that the *container* (not the image) is only reachable from the VM itself.  The declaration

```
ports:
  - 127.0.0.1:4620:80
```

forwards inbound connections on port 4620 on the host to port 80 in the container, but only on the interface bound to 127.0.0.1, which is the dedicated loopback interface (often named `lo`).  When you try to contact it from the host, it arrives on the VM's external IP 192.168.10.35, but nothing is listening there.

If you remove the explicit port binding, Docker will listen on all interfaces, which is usually what you want, and then you should be able to reach the container via the VM's external IP address.

```
ports:
  - '4620:80'
```

(Terminology: an image is a set of static filesystem content; you launch containers from an image and make network connections to the running containers.  You can't directly see what's inside an image, an image doesn't have any running processes, and you can't connect to an image on its own.)